# How to pass declared table to procedure as parameter?; How to access inside procedure the result cursor of another procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, resultset, hsqldb, database-cursor

1. I want to pass a declared table (or a cursor) to a procedure (or a function) as a parameter.
   For example, in the following code, I want to pass the declared table `temp_table` to the procedure `calculate_something_2` as a parameter.
2. I want to get inside a procedure the result cursor of another procedure.
   For example, in the following code, I want to get inside `calculate_something_1` the result cursor of `calculate_something_2`.

I have seen similar things being done in other databases, but **is it possible to do any of these in HSQLDB?**

I have looked at the [documentation](https://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html) but could not find any way to do it.

The following code is the basic idea of what I want to achieve. However, it does not work.

```
create procedure calculate_something_1(in data int)
        modifies sql data
        dynamic result sets 1
    begin atomic

        declare table temp_table (id int, quantity int);

        insert into temp_table values
            (1, 10),
            (2, 20),
            (3, 30);

        declare result_cursor cursor for 
            select id from (call calculate_something_2(temp_table)) where id > 10;
        open result_cursor;
    end;

create procedure calculate_something_2(in t table)
        modifies sql data
        dynamic result sets 1
    begin atomic

        declare result_cursor cursor for 
            select id from t where id > 5;
        open result_cursor;
    end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to pass cursors or tables among PROCEDUREs.

You can define the shared tables as `CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE` and reference them in different procedures.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This can probably work in my case. I've read the documentation http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#sgc_temp_tables but it's rather short and lacks examples. Why using a global temp table here and not local? Do global and local temp tables have different scopes? And where are they supposed to be defined (within a procedure? outside of a procedure?)

Comment: As local temp tables disappear when a session is closed, they cannot be referenced in functions and procedures which are not dependent on any session. The global temp tables are defined just like persistent tables.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I wanted to know!